# WebBrowser - empty DocumentText

Tags: c#, browser

I'm trying to use `WebBrowser` class, but of course it doesn't work.

My code:

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");

while(browser.DocumentText == "")
{
    continue;
}
string html = browser.DocumentText;
```

`browser.DocumentText` is always `""`. Why?

Comment: Well, right off the bat, I can almost guarantee that `Navigate` is NOT an asynchronous function, thus `DocumentText` will not change after Navigate returns--in other words, this will be an infinite loop whenever `DocumentText` is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WebBrowser isn't going to do it's job until the current thread finishes it's work, if you changed it to be something like this:

```
        WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
        browser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
        browser.Navigated += (s, e) =>
            {
                var html = browser.DocumentText;
            };
```

The variable will be set.

But, as others have mentioned, the document completed is a better event to attach to, as at that time, the entire document will be completed (appropriate name!)

```
        WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
        browser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");

        browser.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                var html = browser.DocumentText;
                html.ToString();
            };
```

Comment: It works, but it doesn't load HTML with javascript. I can use HttpWebRequest, but I need javascript. Help me.

Comment: @carck3r What do you mean by "need javascript"? The javascript will either be inline and loaded by either of those two methods, or are accessible by separate web calls.

Comment: @carck3r If you look at the source of that page in a typical browser, you will see stuff like `<noscript>Update Your Browser or Enable Javascript.</noscript>` That's built into the page. If you want something that will parse your javascript for you, you'll have to write it yourself. The webbrowser control will display it for you in a web form, and will parse the javascript for you though.

Comment: @carck3r The WebBrowser uses the IE rendering engine. If you ask for the document text, you'll get the same thing that view source gives you in IE. But the presentation will also be the same as the IE rendering engine, and it will parse and evaluate the javascript just like IE would. It is not really possible to get what you're asking without domain specific information, as javascript doesn't always stop modifying a page. It could modify that page continuously.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `DocumentCompleted` event, and if you don't have WebForms application, also ApplicationContext might be needed.

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Context ctx = new Context();
        Application.Run(ctx);

        // ctx.Html; -- your html
    }
}

class Context : ApplicationContext
{
    public string Html { get; set; }

    public Context()
    {
        WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
        browser.AllowNavigation = true;
        browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(browser_DocumentCompleted);
        browser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
    }

    void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Html = ((WebBrowser)sender).DocumentText;
        this.ExitThread();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Attach to the `DocumentCompleted` event, the code is as below

```
browser.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    string html = browser.DocumentText;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the DocumentText you should handle the DocumentCompleted event

```
  browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(browser_DocumentCompleted);
```

See event below

```
void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
        string text = wb.DocumentText;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
string url = string.Empty:
string html = "http://www.google.com/";
string url = html;
if (!url.StartsWith("http://") && !url.StartsWith("https://"))
{
   url = "http://" + url;
}
browser.Navigate(new Uri(url));
```

replace it within your While loop where necessary

Comment: I don't see how this does what it is he's looking for.

Comment: oops I forgot to address the Document portion .. I was under the impression that the Url was not working..my bad