# Web browser control not working to get text

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to get source code of a webpage and save it to richtextbox and that web browser control navigates to new URL. But I'm getting a blank rich text box. Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        webBrowser2.Navigate("http://www.gmail.com");
    }
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(webBrowser2.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            richTextBox1.Text = webBrowser2.DocumentText;
            webBrowser2.Navigate("new URL");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use the `DocumentCompleted` event instead?

Comment: Read this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526161/webbrowser-empty-documenttext
Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

I see two alternatives to what you're doing.

1) Using `DocumentCompleted`:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    webBrowser.Navigate("www.google.com");
}

private void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
    richTextBox.Text = webBrowser.DocumentText;
}
```

2) Using the `WebClient`:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient()) {
        richTextBox.Text = wc.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wihitehead i have tried the 1st method but richtextbox is still blank and new URL also not taking?

Comment: You need to do a little bit of work for yourself.. I omitted various things like subscribing to the event, navigating afterwards.. etc. You need to fill in the blanks that are relevant to you.